# Container with justified text-align in IE

Tags: html, css, layout, block

I have three divs that have fixed widths. My goal is to align these three divs horizontally with equal spacing between each. I have found that the best solution by far is to use a container with "text-align: justify" as seen in this tutorial: http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/.

This method will place equal space between the three divs, regardless of any other factors. I've used this technique very successfully and feel it is far superior to using floats. The only problem, however, is that it doesn't appear to be working in IE 11 and down.

I minimize my HTML, but put "&nbsp" between each div:

```
<div class="block-container">
    <div class="block"></div>&nbsp;
    <div class="block"></div>&nbsp;
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

The "block-container" has these styles applied to make it work:

```
max-width: 1100px;
text-align: justify;
&:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}
```

In every browser except IE, this works fine. I even have the ability to vertically align each div by using "vertical-align: middle". In IE, however, the divs are placed next to each other and not justified in the container. Is there any way that IE would interpret "text-align: justify" or "nbsp" differently?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer from Justify Grid's documentation: http://justifygrid.com/. The trick is to use "text-justify: distribute-all-lines;" on the container element to fix this in IE. I strongly recommend people adopt this method over floats if they want to support IE9. Otherwise switch to flexbox.